# Link in the SMS Text crashes application?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am working on an application in which I get GPS coordinates from the Google's GeoLocation services. I get these successfully but when I make following URL and pass this as text string in the SMS and try to send it to some user, it crashes. Following is the URL:

```
String text = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + locationInfo.getLat() + "," + locationInfo.getLng()";
sendMessgae (text, num);
```

nothing is null, I have cross verified. when I pass simple text, the message is sent. but I have to send this location URL in the message. Please help me out of this. Any help is appreciated....:-)

Comment: Can you please post logcat error.

Comment: @Usama Sarwar I used this `String text = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=0.00,1.0524"; ` to send sms and I am able to send that successfully.

Comment: @PratikSharma ... your comment was helpful. Thanks, It was an extra : which was making app to crash.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar how? then let me convert that into solution. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
String text = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=0.00,1.0524";
sendMessgae (text, num);
```

Thanks.